# jQuery validate - is there anyway to use sub groups?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I use jQuery Validate 1.11.1 and jQuery 1.11.0.

I have a form and it has three pairs of start/end dates. For each pair, I validate if both inputs are filled out or none of them are filled out because it's not allowed to fill out a start date and not the end date and vice-versa; plus, I can't send the form without at least one of the pairs filled out.

Imagine user entering dates only in the start dates, but none in the end dates. I have to show him three error messages, one for each pair. But if the user enters no data, I should send him only one error message.

The problem is that I have four groups, one for each pair and one for the entire form, in other words, the first three pairs are subgroups of the bigger one.

If I place the bigger group in my code in the end, I only get one error message if the user enter no data, but I only get one error message if user enters only start dates as well. If I place the bigger group in the beginning, I get three error messages when user enters just start dates but also get three equal error messages if user sends an empty form.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="msgErros"></div>
<form>
    <label for="dataInicialSolicitacao">Solicita&ccedil;&atilde;o Inicial</label>
    <input type="text" class="data skipOrFillDatasSolicitacao atLeastOneRequired" id="dataInicialSolicitacao" value="" size="12" name="filtro.dataInicialSolicitacao" maxlength="10" />
    <label for="dataFinalSolicitacao">Solicita&ccedil;&atilde;o Final</label>
    <input type="text" class="data skipOrFillDatasSolicitacao atLeastOneRequired" id="dataFinalSolicitacao" value="" size="12" name="filtro.dataFinalSolicitacao" maxlength="10" />
    <br />
    <label for="dataInicialLiberacao">Libera&ccedil;&atilde;o Inicial</label>
    <input type="text" class="data skipOrFillDatasLiberacao atLeastOneRequired" id="dataInicialLiberacao" value="" size="12" name="filtro.dataInicialLiberacao" maxlength="10" />
    <label for="dataFinalLiberacao">Libera&ccedil;&atilde;o Final</label>
    <input type="text" class="data skipOrFillDatasLiberacao atLeastOneRequired" id="dataFinalLiberacao" value="" size="12" name="filtro.dataFinalLiberacao" maxlength="10" />
    <br />
    <label for="dataInicialInternacao">Interna&ccedil;&atilde;o Inicial</label>
    <input type="text" class="data skipOrFillDatasInternacao atLeastOneRequired" id="dataInicialInternacao" value="" size="12" name="filtro.dataInicialInternacao" maxlength="10" />
    <label for="dataFinalInternacao">Interna&ccedil;&atilde;o Final</label>
    <input type="text" class="data skipOrFillDatasInternacao atLeastOneRequired" id="dataFinalInternacao" value="" size="12" name="filtro.dataFinalInternacao" maxlength="10" />
    <br />
    <button>Consultar</button>
    <button type="reset">Limpar</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(".data").mask("99/99/9999").datepicker();

$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        "filtro.dataInicialSolicitacao": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: [2, ".skipOrFillDatasSolicitacao"],
            require_from_group: [2, ".atLeastOneRequired"]
        },
        "filtro.dataFinalSolicitacao": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: [2, ".skipOrFillDatasSolicitacao"],
            require_from_group: [2, ".atLeastOneRequired"]
        },
        "filtro.dataInicialInternacao": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: [2, ".skipOrFillDatasInternacao"],
            require_from_group: [2, ".atLeastOneRequired"]
        },
        "filtro.dataFinalInternacao": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: [2, ".skipOrFillDatasInternacao"],
            require_from_group: [2, ".atLeastOneRequired"]
        },
        "filtro.dataInicialLiberacao": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: [2, ".skipOrFillDatasLiberacao"],
            require_from_group: [2, ".atLeastOneRequired"]
        },
        "filtro.dataFinalLiberacao": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: [2, ".skipOrFillDatasLiberacao"],
            require_from_group: [2, ".atLeastOneRequired"]
        }
    },
    groups: {
        datasSolicitacao: "filtro.dataInicialSolicitacao filtro.dataFinalSolicitacao",
        datasLiberacao: "filtro.dataInicialLiberacao filtro.dataFinalLiberacao",
        datasInternacao: "filtro.dataInicialInternacao filtro.dataFinalInternacao",
        todos: "filtro.dataInicialSolicitacao filtro.dataFinalSolicitacao filtro.dataInicialLiberacao filtro.dataFinalLiberacao filtro.dataInicialInternacao filtro.dataFinalInternacao"
    },
    errorContainer: "#msgErros ul",
    errorLabelContainer: "#msgErros",
    wrapper: "li"
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgioseffi/LevK6/5/) with the bigger group in the end. To test it just enter start dates and press "Consultar", you'll only get one message when I need three. Then press "Limpar" and then "Consultar" and you'll get one message only which is correct.

And here's a variation of the first [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgioseffi/LevK6/6/) with the bigger group in the beginning. To test it just enter start dates and press "Consultar", you'll get three messages, one for each row, and that's correct. Then press "Limpar" and then "Consultar" and you'll get three messages as well, and that's not correct.

Any ideas on how to have the correct behavior happen for both cases?

Comment: Can the one that downvoted the question explain why?